# Algorithm asymptotic-complexity

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I would like to know what is the minimum and maximum value this procedure can return in the following algorithm using the big-theta notation. The algorithm is:

```
procedure F([1..n])
   s = 0
   for i = 1 to n
      j = min(max(i,A[i]),n³) 
      s = s + j
   return s
```

Comment: What does this line mean: ` = min{max{,[]},n³} `?  Is it the same as ` = min(max(, []), n^3)`?  (Also, how are you typing in those stylized letters(, , )?)

Comment: Where are you stuck? At the moment you've just posted your (presumably homework) question, and shown no signs of having attempted to solve it. As a hint, figure out upper and lower bounds in terms of i and n for the value assigned to j inside the loop.

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: Not all users can see what you have posted. Don't (ab)use Unicode when you don't have to.

Comment: I tried to test the algorithm with i = 10 but I didnt find any hint about the complexity

Comment: If you set all the array elements to -infinity, what is the return value? If you sent all the array elements to +infinity, what is the return value?

Comment: For -infinity and n=5 the return value is s=15.For +infinity and n=5 the return value is s = 500.

Comment: And for arbitrary n? Can you find a mathematical expression (for example, involving a summation sign) that gives you the result of F in the cases where all the A[i] are +infinity, or they're all -infinity? How about just for the line that assigns to j? There it could be a mathematical expression that involves one or both of i and n.

Comment: I think of : F = s + i in the cases where all the A[i] are -infinity and F = s + n³ in the cases where all the A[i] are +infinity.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: removed original answer as it was for the wrong question.

The analysis hinges on the following line:

```
min(max(i,A[i]),n³)
```

If we figure out the cases for this then we can easily figure the cases for the result. We must answer whether `i > A[i]` and then whether the greater of `i` and `A[i]` is greater than `n^3`.

1. `i > A[i]` and `i > n^3`. This cannot be the case because `i <= n` and `i, n` are integers.
2. `i > A[i]` and `i < n^3`. This can happen if, e.g., `A[i] = -1`. In this case, we are adding `i` together for `0 <= i <= n`. This comes out as `n(n+1)/2`, which is `O(n^2)`. (I am using `O` but Theta applies as well).
3. `i < A[i]` and `A[i] < n^3`. This can happen if `i + 1<= A[i] <= n^3 - 1` and `n > 2`. In this case, we are adding `i + 1` together `n` times, for `i` equal `1` to `n`, or we are adding `n^3 - 1` together `n` times. On the low end we get `n(n-1)/2 - n`, as before with the `-n` term for the `-1`, and on the high end we get `n^4 - n`; somewhere between `O(n^2)` and `O(n^4)`.
4. `i < A[i]` and `A[i] > n^3`. This can happen if `A[i] > n^3`. In this case we have `n^3` summed `n` times for `n^4`, `O(n^4)`.

Based on the above, my thinking is that the lower bound on the best case is `Omega(n^2)` and the upper bound on the worst case is `O(n^4)`. Both of these bounds are tight for their respective cases, but since they are not the same we cannot give a single tight bound for the rate of growth of the result.

Comment: I believe the question is about the value of the return value, not about the time complexity.

Comment: Indeed, my question is about the return value complexity. I am sorry if I didnt make it clear.

Comment: @johnsol I'm sorry, I saw the title and the code and assumed this was a simpler problem than it was. I will think about this for a moment and if I can edit this answer I will, else I will delete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help